# How to fix " --asar does not take any arguments, it only has sub-properties" warning

Tags: build, electron, asar

At the last step of my application when I want to build my desktop app (for windows 10 OS) with "npm run package-win" command I am getting the same warning in the title. Other problem is application's exe file occurs but gives error. "The code execution cannot proceed because ffmpeg.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem."

I reinstalled the program several times, I changed my package.json's scripts I thought it is because of asar's dependencies

PS C:\Users\osman.turalioglu\Projects\project> npm run package-win

> project@1.0.0 package-win C:\Users\osman.turalioglu\Projects\project>
>   electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="project"
>   WARNING: --asar does not take any arguments, it only has sub-properties (see --help)
>   Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v5.0.6
>   Wrote new app to release-builds\project-win32-ia32

I expect my desktopp app' exe file builded

Comment: I'm stuck here. When the answer comes i will continue TY

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hi the error its pretty explicit, go to package.json on scripts section on package-win line, look for --asar=true remove the true leaving only --asar, the asar property is true by default

Comment: Hi ty for your response. I am gonna test it

Comment: Ty for your response I fixed it  and it works. TY very much